# Replace Array items without mutating in javascript

Tags: reactjs, redux

My initial state of the object is 
{
"value":"",
"label":""
}

Once I call an API I will get the response like
[
{
"_id":"234234234",
"name":"xyz"
},
{
"_id":"345345345",
"name":"adwwd"
}
]

I want the output state to look like this
[{"value":"xyz","label":"xyz"},{"value":"adwwd","label":"adwwd"}]

Now how can I update my state with the values from the response without mutating it?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to end up with, and what you've tried?

Comment: return [...response.map(items=>{Object.assign({},items,{value:item.name,label:item.name})})]

Comment: response is coming from the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your arrow function return value inside `{}` which means that it is executed, just like `function(){ ... }`. To return it, you need to include `return`, e.g. `.map( item => { return ... } )`. Or if you want to use arrow function shorthand, you can return an object by *putting the object inside parentheses*, like this: `item => ({ value:..., label:... })`. This means you don't need to use `Object.assign`, unless you want to include `_id` and `name`.

Also, you had used `item` and `items`, which may have caused an issue.

Putting it together:

```
return response.map(item=>({ value:item.name, label:item.name }))
// returns `[{"value":"xyz","label":"xyz"},{"value":"adwwd","label":"adwwd"}]`
```

Comment: Awesome it Worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to store the api response on another property in your state called `data` for example, you could do:

```
...
case RECEIVED_RESPONSE:
    return {
        ...state,
        data: [
            ...state.data,
            ...action.payload
        ]
    }
...
```

NOTE: This requires support for both Array and Object spread, if you are just writing es5 then the following is functionally equivalent:

```
...
case RECEIVED_RESPONSE:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: state.data.concat(action.payload)
    }
...
```

Further information re: immutable update patterns can be found in the Redux docs here -- http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html

Comment: Hi,I dont want the full response from the API,I just need to take the name from the response and return a new array..